# Syntax for plotting a CDF of experimental data

Tags: plotting

What is the syntax for plotting cumulative distribution function of the following collected data {0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 0.9, 0.3, 0.2}?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the documentation at all? Have you attempted anything on your own?

Comment: @Akda I suggest you like at `EmpiricalDistribution`: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EmpiricalDistribution.html

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following will give you an idea of the functions you should be looking at in the documentation.

```
data = {0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 0.9, 0.3, 0.2};
DiscretePlot[CDF[EmpiricalDistribution[data], x], {x, 0, 1, .04}]
```

[image: plot]